# перебор из БД по разным необязательным параметрам в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных

Есть программа, которая ищет по БД перебором сотрудников, проверяя их по необязательным параметрам, например:

```
position = input('enter position')
sex = input('sex')
age = input('age')
...etc
```

далее программа перебором (по определенным причинам нужен именно перебор) проверяет каждого сотрудника на соответствие введенным критериям, и если совпадает- выводит сотрудника например в `print()`.
Вся загвоздка в том, что параметры не обязательные, и если ничего не введено- переменной присваивается `null`. 
первое что приходит в голову- проверять по всем комбинациям параметров, например:

```
if position != null and sex != null and age != null:
    print('yep!')
elif position == null and sex != null and age != null:
    print('yep2!')
...etc
```

что напоминает костыль и если параметров много- невозможно будет перебрать все комбинации. как организовать проверку по-питоновски лаконично и без костылей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала я бы посоветовал присваивать пустым переменным не null, a None - в этом случае будут корректно работать предикаты. А затем делаете простейший итератор:

```
sex = None
position = "blah"
age=96

for elem in (position, sex, age):
    if elem:
        print(elem)
```

Получим:

```
blah
96
```

Вообще, если у вас несколько переменных, я бы советовал загнать их в словарь. Тогда все будет намного проще - не нужно будет вручную переписывать цикл для итератора:

```
params={}
params["sex"] = None
params["position"] = "queen"
params["age"] = 96

for elem in params.keys():
    if params[elem]:
        print(params[elem])
```

Получим:

```
queen
96
```